# Acro package: Control capitalization of prefix "The" on first use?

Tags: acro

[This Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542461) shows how to prefix the long form of an acronym with "the" on the first occurrence.  Is there any way to control capitalization of the leading "T"?  Here is an example of when I don't and do need capitalization:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
 short = CD ,
 long = compact disc
 }

\DeclareAcronym{css}{
 short = CSS ,
 long = Centre for Spaghetti Studies
 } 
\NewAcroTemplate{long-short-the}{%
 \acroiffirstTF{%
 the %%%%%%%%%% No capital "T"
 \acrowrite{long}%
 \acspace(%
 \acroifT{foreign}{\acrowrite{foreign}, }%
 \acrowrite{short}%
 \acroifT{alt}{ \acrotranslate{or} \acrowrite{alt}}%
 \acrogroupcite
 )%
 }%
 {\acrowrite{short}}%
 } 
\begin{document}

\textbf{Want no capital "T", as defined above}

Blah blah \ac[first-style=long-short-the]{cd}, \ac{css}.

Blah blah \ac[first-style=long-short-the]{cd}.

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\acresetall

\textbf{Want capital "T" but don't get it}

\Ac[first-style=long-short-the]{cd}, \ac{css}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you follow [cgnieder's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542480/106162)? It works straight out of the box.

Comment: I'm not certain but I guess passing the `first-style` key to `\Ac` is overriding the `\acroupper` that `\Ac` would ordinarily set. This might be more bug than design, I'd need to investigate, but `acro` is built to handle this sort of thing with `\DeclareAcroArticle`/`\NewAcroCommand` and I don't see a reason not to use those based on the example use case given.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm missing something.  You pointed to an answer in the same Q&A that I cited.  My MWE above is in fact adapted from that answer.  Since I'm not seeing it, can you please point to how that answer redresses the capitalization problem of this question?  I apologize if there's something obvious I'm overlooking.

Comment: Your question here is adapted from [Ulrike Fischer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542463/106162), I am saying your issue here is already resolved if you follow instead [cgnieder's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542480/106162)

Comment: -cgnieder's answer works flawlessly. I could not test drive it at the time of the Q&A because my environment was too out-of-date. I use Cygwin to ensure package compatibility, but that machine was subject to firewall and policy restrictions. I might have been able to place the package files in the working folder, but went with Ulrike's answer because it was simpler and I could almost understand it. While I don't understand cgnieder's answer, it works across use cases. Should this question be marked as dupe? The question is different, but cgnieder's answer addresses both questions.

Comment: Actually, cgnieder's answer does not work for the case where you want no capitalization of the 1st letter *and* possessive ending (`\dacg`).  I will post a comment on the answer asking whether that use case can be covered.

Comment: Dupe was my first thought, probably still appropriate, but I've put an answer here that hopefully helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is essentially answered in your previous question [Best practice to deal with need for "the" only for expanded acronym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542461/106162) by [cgnieder's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542480/106162) but there's evidently some confusion and I think I can usefully supplement those answers with some information here.

The rough philosophy of `acro` (to my mind at least) is that the acronym templates indicate what properties of the acronym are to be printed: either directly (`short`, `long`, `alt`) or indirectly (`short-long`, `long-short`, `single`) while the acronym command (`\ac`, `\Acs`, `\acfp`) specifies any additional context in which it should be used (such as plural) alongside the template.
These switches can then propagate where appropriate e.g. `\acfp{CD}` becomes `compact discs (CDs)` and can be modified on a per-acronym basis (see the example definition of `ufo` using `long-indefinite = an` in the `acro` documentation).

The plural and indefinite articles are built-in instances of Endings and Articles, alternatives can be defined with `\DeclareAcroEnding` and `\DeclareAcroArticle`.  These create a large set of properties for `\DeclareAcronym` alongside defaults and a switch usable in `\NewAcroCommand`.
The indefinite article is set by `\DeclareAcroArticle{indefinite}{a}` which creates keys like `short-indefinite` that can override the default `a` as appropriate. In this instance we would do `\DeclareAcroArticle{definite}{the}` which shouldn't require any additional property setting in `\DeclareAcronym`s.

So far this only deals with acronym properties, we still need to create the necessary `\ac` variants.
The natural way to do this would be as follows (prefixing the definite variants with `d`):
`\dac` is just a variant of `\ac` prefaced by the definite article, so we need the `\acrodefinite` switch alongisde calling the `first` template, so

```
\NewAcroCommand\dac{m}{\acrodefinite\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}
```

to create an uppercased variant we insert `\acroupper` in addition to everything else

```
\NewAcroCommand\Dac{m}{\acroupper\acrodefinite\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}
```

for plural variants of `\dac` and `\Dac` we need to throw in `\acroplural` to both the normal and uppercased versions

```
\NewAcroCommand\dacp{m}{\acrodefinite\acroplural\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}
\NewAcroCommand\Dacp{m}{\acroupper\acrodefinite\acroplural\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}
```

while to define the equivalent variants specifically for the `short` form we need to duplicate again switching `first` for `short` in `\UseAcroTemplate`

```
\NewAcroCommand\dacs{m}{\acrodefinite\UseAcroTemplate{short}{#1}}
\NewAcroCommand\Dacs{m}{\acroupper\acrodefinite\UseAcroTemplate{short}{#1}}
\NewAcroCommand\dacsp{m}{\acrodefinite\acroplural\UseAcroTemplate{short}{#1}}
\NewAcroCommand\Dacsp{m}{\acroupper\acrodefinite\acroplural\UseAcroTemplate{short}{#1}}
```

and so on. Unfortunately all necessary variants you will need have to be individually defined in this fashion, but this should be define once to use many times.

Having said all that, as "the" will always be used in English, I would probably prefer writing it explicitly as `the \ac{cd}` as there's no scope for the definite article to change depending on whether the first/short/long form is used.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  I'm not sure if I fully understood your last paragraph.  In English, "the" is often (not always) dropped because the short form is treated like a person's name, even though it's the name of an organization.

Comment: @user2153235 I'm struggling for an example I would see as correct outside of maybe cases where I would define the long form itself inclusive of the "the". If you have a case where the definite article should change (or be selectively omitted) between the long/first and short forms then definitely do this. However there's overhead involved so if it all amounts to `\NewDocumentCommand\dac{m}{the \ac{#1}}` then do that, or even better for readability/portability just write the `the` explicitly.

Comment: It's quite possible that I am misunderstanding your last paragraph, but it seems to say that "the" will always either present or not present, regardless of whether an organization's name is in short or long form. An example where that is not the case is NASA. In long form, it sounds weird without "the". In short form, it sounds weird if preceded by "the". For the organizational names I use, this is not uncommon, so I prefer to avoid an explicit "the". I am never sure whether the organizational name will remain in long or short form as the document is revised.