Find documentation for old version of acro package
I am writing a report using the acro package, for which I define acronyms in acronyms.tex.  It's a file that I keep adding to as I write more reports. It contains a commented out MWE with complicated (to me) acro commands from long ago.  I forgot how they worked, so I pasted it into a new MWE.tex, ran pdflatex on it, and got:
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
                   \exp_stop_f:
l.69 \Dacg{css}
                mandate is broad.
?
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again>
                   \exp_stop_f:
l.69 \Dacg{css}
                mandate is broad.
End of file on the terminal!

The relevant part of MWE.tex that I'm trying to troubleshoot seems to be:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcroArticle{definite}{the}
\DeclareAcroEnding{possessive}{'s}{'s}

\NewAcroCommand\dac{m}{\acrodefinite\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}
\NewAcroCommand\Dac{m}{\acroupper\acrodefinite\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}

\NewAcroCommand\Dacg{m}{%
  \acroupper
  \acrodefinite
  \acropossessive
  \UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}%
}

I found the documentation for the current acro package here, which is for version 3.8.  It says:

\NewAcroCommand{⟨command⟩}{⟨arg. spec.⟩}{⟨code⟩}

This creates the new command ⟨command⟩ with the
argument specification10 so⟨arg. spec.⟩ and
replacement text ⟨code⟩. There are significant
differences to \NewAcroCommand: the new command
always has two additional arguments: an optional
star and an optional argument for options. You
can ignore this fact in your definition, though.
However, the command must at least have one
argument and the first argument must refer to
the ID. Everything else is up to you

The syntax doesn't match what's in MWE.tex because \NewAcroCommand is followed by { in the documentation, but not in MWE.tex.  I also noted the passage "There are significant differences to \NewAcroCommand...", so I checked acro.sty in the texmf tree for the report that I'm writing.  It is version 3.7, one earlier than the documentation.  It is possible that the MWE.tex code is from before acro 3.7, but I thought I'd check if the acro 3.7 documentation for \NewAcroCommand matches the MWE.tex code.
Starting with this comment, I found the acro 3.7 style file here.  To find the documentation, I backed up to the texmf-dist component of the path and descended into the doc subfolder.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed from there.  None of the folders seem to be for 3rd party packages.
How does one access documentation for older versions of packages?  What about specifically for the acro package?
P.S. I tried the ftp URL here, but both
Chrome and Firefox asks for a tool to use.
Afternote: I found a manual for an even older acro 2.10 here.  Even though the syntax definition shows \NewAcroCommand{, the examples in Section 11 shows code in which \NewAcroCommand is not followed by curly braces.  I am at a loss as to how to interpret the syntax definition, but that is the topic of another question.  In fact, even for the documentation of the current version 3.8 here, I found the example code in Section 30 to also be without an immediately following {.  Therefore, this disparity between the syntax definition and the example code is not due to changes in acro version.

it is standard tex syntax that if the argument is a single token you can omit the braces. so \newcommand{\foo}{aaa}  and \newcommand\foo{aaa} parse the same way: the latex macro code really can not tell which input form was used. similarly \frac12 works and is \frac{1}{2} although I would not recommend doing that

Thanks for that, David.

The MWE is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542480/106162, it works for me in TL 2022 with acro 3.8, but fails with TL 2023 so I guess something has changed in the l3kernel to cause issues. The example works in TL 2023 with  short-definite = x so I guess short-definite = \nospace is causing something problematic.
As far as the documentation you're basically in the right place, acro-manual.pdf can be found under doc/latex/acro at https://tug.org/svn/texlive/branches/branch2022/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/acro/acro-manual.pdf?revision=62886&view=co. For acro, the PDF manual can be found on the github repository, e.g. for acro v2 https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/blob/747d3c48587305df2c2bb6e8df9b92db9c3669fe/acro-manual.pdf. However, the problem is not due to difference acro versions.
EDIT: To be exact the problem comes with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcroArticle{definite}{the}

\NewAcroCommand\dac{m}{\acrodefinite\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}
\NewAcroCommand\Dac{m}{\acroupper\acrodefinite\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}

\DeclareAcronym{css}{
  short = CSS ,
  long = Centre for Spaghetti Studies ,
  short-definite = \nospace,
}

\begin{document}
\Dac{css}
\dac{css}
\Dac{css}
\end{document}

I think the underlying problem is \__acro_article:nnn introduces a \exp_stop_f: which gets into the argument of \text_titlecase_first:n as \text_titlecase_first:n {\nospace \exp_stop_f: CSS} and this causes an error with a more recent kernel.
At first glance, the \exp_stop_f: doesn't do anything more than introduce the space after the article, so it may be possible to redefine \__acro_article:nnn as
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \__acro_article:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \bool_if:cT {l__acro_article_#3_bool}
      {
        \tl_map_break:n
          { \acro_property_get:nn {#1} {#2-#3} \c_space_tl }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

but this could well break other things.

Thanks, Dai Bowen.  Yes, you did find the Q&A where the MWE came from.  I appreciate you troubleshooting the problem with short-definite = \nospace.  Regarding the page https://tug.org/svn/texlive/branches/branch2022/Master/texmf-dist/doc, would you know the logic behind the subfolders?  For example, why acro is in the latex subfolder but not the luatex folder?  I appreciate your pointer to github for documentation for older package versions.

Given that the MWE is broken, I believe that my solution is to go back to the Q&A from which the MWE comes and follow the second answer by Ulrike Fischer.  I don't welcome this, not because the answer bad, but because I don't understand the acro code.  Every time I try to read the manual, I am unable to understand it.  It probably serves as a great reference manual for those who already know who the commands work together and just need to look up the details.

I'm sure someone explains it better elsewhere, but afaik the texmf structure represents minimum support. acro should not be in plain or luatex as it requires the LaTeX format, it could be in lualatex or xelatex, but that is overspecifying as it does not explicitly need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX as opposed to jus the LaTeX format, and these can also source from latex.

OK, thanks, Dai. Regarding Ulrike's solution, unfortunately, it doesn't modify capitalization in response to \Ac (as opposed \ac). I've posted a comment asking whether it would be a quick modification to respect the capitalization implied by \Ac. As well, the solution requires a long optional argument to \ac, so I would probably define a new command to make that unnecessary.

The definite article feature is so important to not having to manually keep track of first occurrence of each acronym that I was tempted to go back to TexLive 2022.  However, it seems a "mission" that will never end. Pity that I upgraded my Cygwin. I am surprised that my packages were so old that the commands in the MWE were not broken as recently as May 2024.

I modified the MWE to show that the command definitions can be left in MWE code as long as the source code doesn't invoke the commands that handle the definite article (those starting with \D or \d). When the issue with l3kernel is resolved in future TexLive's, they will still be ready for use. The new MWE shows that the commands for possessive s can still be used. Breaking definite articles is a huge handicap. All first uses of an acronym need to be manually tracked. Not having to do so is a main reason for using acronym packages.

I tried to delve into how \nospace causes the problem.  While much can be found online, the only relevant link is to the LAMS-TEX manual. It is scanned and takes a long time to OCR. Even then, searching through occurrences of \nospace has made me none the wiser.  My TeX-fu is insufficient.

Yes, we've previously discussed the advantage of using this approach which hardcodes less. Unfortunately the bug is probably in acro, but l3kernel has just changed to now expose the issue. I've further tracked it down to the combination of \acroupper\acrodefinite and short-definite=\nospace (so a \dacg defined without \acroupper works fine) but I still need to work out exactly what goes wrong.

I am cheering for you, Dai Bowen.  For selfish reasons!
